# Why is my Python code not evaluating booleans correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, boolean, boolean-logic

I'm a beginner to Python and I saw a tutorial by Cory Schafer on YouTube about Booleans and Conditionals. He had a segment when he was trying to show what values Python considers as False. He tests them one by one, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient/fun way to do it so I tried coming up with this for loop statement. I'm expecting the output to be 8 lines of Evaluated to False, but I keep getting Evaluated to True. Could someone enlighten me? Thank you!

```
condition = (False, None, 0, 0.00, '', (), [], {})

for i in condition:
    if condition:    # It is assumed that condition == true here, right? 
        print('Evaluated to True')
    else:
        print('Evaluated to False ')

#OUT: 
Evaluated to True
Evaluated to True
Evaluated to True
Evaluated to True
Evaluated to True
Evaluated to True
Evaluated to True
Evaluated to True
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `if condition` to `if i`. You want to test each of the individual items that have been pulled out of the `condition` tuple, as opposed to testing the entire tuple 8 times.

Clearer naming would obviate this issue. I advise always giving collections plural names with an `s` at the end. Then you can write this, which reads more naturally:

```
conditions = (False, None, 0, 0.00, '', (), [], {})

for condition in conditions:
    if condition:    # It is assumed that condition == true here, right? 
        print('Evaluated to True')
    else:
        print('Evaluated to False ')
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought the clearer naming bit was actually really smart. Will start doing that from now on!

Answer (score 1):

Careful! You are evaluating the full tuple, each time in your loop (therefore, evaluating the same object) not the individual items. Also, you are getting True, because non empty lists/tuples/dictionaries will evaluate to True always, in comparison to empty ones which evaluate to False as you can see in your last 3 iterations.

You should change the line when you evaluate to `i` instead of `condition`:

```
condition = (False, None, 0, 0.00, '', (), [], {})

for i in condition:
    if i: 
        print('Evaluated to True')
    else:
        print('Evaluated to False')
```

This rightfully returns:

```
Evaluated to False 
Evaluated to False 
Evaluated to False 
Evaluated to False 
Evaluated to False 
Evaluated to False 
Evaluated to False 
Evaluated to False
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I was also wondering why I kept getting True, and just clarifying your explanation as to why, is it because my 'condition' tuple is not empty even though it is filled with elements that are supposedly empty and/or false?

Comment: Exactly, if you evaluate the tuple, you are evaluating that object, not the contents inside it.

Answer (score -1):

In the if statement replace condition with i

```
condition = (False, None, 0, 0.00, '', (), [], {})

for i in condition:
    if condition:
        print("Evaluated to True")
    else:
        print("Evaluated to False")
```